# Django annotation on (model → FK → model) relation

Tags: python, django

Galaxies across the universe host millions/billions of stars, each belonging to a specific type, depending on its physical properties (Red stars, Blue Supergiant, White Dwarf, etc). For each Star in my database, I'm trying to find the number of distinct galaxies that are also home for some star of that same type.

```
class Galaxy(Model):
    ...

class Star(Model):
     galaxy = ForeignKey(Galaxy, related_name='stars')
     type = CharField(...)
```

Performing this query individually for each Star might be comfortably done by:

```
star = <some_Star>

desired_galaxies = Galaxy.objects.filter(stars__type=star.type).distinct()
desired_count = desired_galaxies.count()
```

Or even, albeit more redundant:

```
desired_count = Star.objects.filter(galaxy__stars__type=star.type).values('galaxy').distinct()
```

This get a little fuzzier when I try to get the *count* result for all the stars in a "single" query:

```
all_stars = Star.objects.annotate(desired_count=...)
```

The main reason I want to do that is to be capable of sorting `Star.objects.order_by('desired_count')` in a clean way.

What I've tried so far:

```
Star.annotate(desired_count=Count('galaxy', filter=Q(galaxy__stars__type=F('type')), distinct=True))
```

But this annotates `1` for every star. I guess I'll have to go for `OuterRef, Subquery` here, but not sure on how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't provide a way to define multi-valued relationships between models that don't involve foreign keys yet. If it did you could do something like

```py
class Galaxy(Model):
    ...

class Star(Model):
    galaxy = ForeignKey(Galaxy, related_name='stars')
    type = CharField(...)
    same_type_stars = Relation(
        'self', from_fields=('type',), to_fields=('type',)
    )

Star.objects.annotate(
    galaxies_count=Count('same_type_stars__galaxy', distinct=True)
)
```

Which would result in something along

```sql
SELECT
  star.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT same_star_type.galaxy_id) galaxies_count
FROM star
LEFT JOIN star same_star_type ON (same_star_type.type = star.type)
GROUP BY star.id
```

If you want to achieve something similar you'll need to use subquery for now

```py
Star.objects.annotate(
    galaxies_count=Subquery(Star.objects.filter(
        type=OuterRef('type'),
    ).values('type').values(
        inner_count=Count('galaxy', distinct=True),
    ))
)
```

Which would result in something along

```sql
SELECT
   star.*,
   (
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT inner_star.galaxy_id)
       FROM star inner_star
       WHERE inner_star.type = star.type
       GROUP BY inner_star.type
   ) galaxies_count
FROM star
```

Which likely perform poorly on some databases that don't materialize correlated subqueries (e.g. MySQL). In all cases **make sure you index `Star.type`** otherwise you'll get bad performance no matter what. A composite index on `('type', 'galaxy')` might be even better as it might allow you to perform index only scan (e.g. on PostgreSQL).

Comment: that looks promising. I tried using the subquery you suggested; it returns an error: AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'split'. Maybe there's some little detail missing?

Comment: Are you sure you added the `inner_count=` in the `values` call of the subquery? I just tried out the query against Django 3.1.2 and it's working for me.

Comment: After making the changes, it is working perfectly, I'm taking your answer as accepted :) One more thing if you could clarify on "...A composite index on ('type', 'galaxy') might be even better..." ;  even if galaxy is already a FK, it still makes a difference inside a composite index?

Comment: @L.B. yes it does, at least on PostgreSQL where I tested it. First thing first, you want to index on `Star.type` anyway since it's a filtering criteria. Having both `star` and `galaxy_id` in the same index will avoid lookups against the heap on PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-index-only-scans.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` to get the count:

```
Star.objects.values('type').annotate(desired_count=Count('galaxy')).values('type', 'desired_count')
```

Comment: It counts for stars of the same type on the same galaxy multiple times. For example if galaxy Andromeda has 3 stars of type Blue, that will add a 3 to the desired count of Blue stars within Andromeda

Comment: Alright it just needed a ```Count('galaxy', distinct=True)``` to give me the right results. What I'm still missing is how to perform the ```Star.objects.order_by('desired_count')```.

Comment: I tried with Subquery and Outerref, but I could not produce the correct results.